# Forcing no-cache for internet explorer over HTTPS with HTTP response headers?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, http, caching, weblogic

So, I recently found this little gem.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308

Essentially, IE doesn't haven't `Cache-Control: no-cache` properly over HTTPs, which breaks the download. However, I need to disable caching for a number of responses across my application which hit the same IO write path, which I can easily control.

Is there a way to get around this issue so that I can force no-caching in IE over HTTPS using nothing but response headers? It's unrealistic to expect my users to do a registry change to fix the broken behavior of IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good solution. You can try adding the timestamp to your requests, though.

Comment: I use this method for ajax in ie as it caches the request!!

Answer (score 0):

I just do this to clear out the cache headers set by the web container and it has worked fine

```
response.reset(); //workaround IE restriction against streaming to cache from SSL
response.setContentType("myMIMEType");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + whateverGoesHere + "\"");
```

Then send the file to output stream.  Obviously if you want it rendered inside the browser window rather than a file save dialog, you wouldn't put do the `attachment;` disposition type.

Comment: Should this somehow prevent caching, or allow Cache-Control to not cause absolute breakage? I'm trying both now.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same problem with IE8 (but not IE9), found the fix to be:

```
Pragma: private
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
```

Just in case somebody is still looking.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
Pragma: no-cache
```

From the [HTTP Spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.32)

Comment: This exhibits the same breakage.